# Tactics with variable arity

Tags: coq, variadic, ltac

Say I want to have a tactic to clear multiple hypothesis at once, to do something like `clear_multiple H1, H2, H3.`. I tried to do that using pairs, like the following:

```
Ltac clear_multiple arg :=
match arg with
| (?f, ?s) => clear s; clear_multiple f
| ?f => clear f
end.
```

But then, the problem is that I have to place parenthesis to have a `Prod`:

```
Variable A: Prop.

Goal A -> A -> A -> True.
intros.
clear_multiple (H, H0, H1).
```

My question is, how to do that without using `Prod`s ?

---

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727363/coq-ltac-definitions-over-variable-argument-lists), but it is not exactly what I want, since the number of arguments I want is not known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like to know that the `clear` tactic can take multiple arguments, so you do not need to define a new tactic: you can just write `clear H H0 H1`.

Of course, you might want to define such n-ary tactics for other tasks.  Coq has a [tactic notation mechanism](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/syntax-extensions.html#sec650) that supports such definitions.  Unfortunately, they are not too powerful: you can only pass a list of arguments of a certain kind to a tactic that expects multiple arguments (like `clear`); I don't think it can give you a list that you can iterate on programmatically.

Comment: Here is something more on the issue: https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/1222#issuecomment-337488931